# PHP Passing Value on Cart

Tags: php, session, addition, cart

I have created a shopping cart page using PHP. Now the problem I encountered was that, when I add a product to the cart from the product list, what happens is that only the 1st product on the list is added.

When I add another product (since every product on the list has it's own Add to Cart button), the 1st product is added again. Doesn't matter what item I choose, it still end up with the 1st product being added.

Am I missing something?

Here's my code:

Product List:

```
    <?php do { ?>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['pname']; ?></td>
          <td colspan="1"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['pdesc']; ?></td>
          <td colspan="1"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['price']; ?></td>
          <td colspan="1"><center><img src="admin/<?php echo $prorow['image']; ?>" width="80" height="80" />
          <td colspan="1">
              <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to Cart">
          </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } while ($prorow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
```

I am passing values using hidden input types.

Add to Cart:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'abra', 'abra','abra') or die("Could not connect database");

    $cname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $pid=mysql_escape_string($_POST['proID']);
    $pname=mysql_escape_string($_POST['proName']);
    $price=mysql_escape_string($_POST['proPRICE']);
    $qty=mysql_escape_string($_POST['qty']);


$addtocart = "INSERT INTO cart_track (bid, cName, pname, price, qty) VALUES ('$pid', '$cname', '$pname', '$price', '$qty')";

mysqli_query($con,$addtocart);
header("location:showcart.php");
exit;

ob_end_flush()
 ?>
```

Show Cart:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'abra', 'abra','abra') or die("Could not connect database");

 //Check if user wants to checkout or shop:
if(isset($_POST['checkout']))
{

    header("location:orders.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['shop']))
{
    header("location:prodtable.php");
}
//retrieve items . use session_id and/or datetime
//$PHPSESSID=session_id();
$showcart = "SELECT * from cart_track INNER JOIN products ON bid=pId WHERE bid=pId";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $showcart);


if(!$result)
{
$err=true;
//i recommend writing this error to a log or some text file, for security reasons.
$errmsg=mysql_error();
}
else
{
$err=false;
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
?>
```

I suspect that the mistake is on the Product List code, but I have the AddtoCart file checked also.

Comment: the first snippet, can you paste the whole form (it looks like it should be a form)? You're also mixing `mysqli` and `mysql`, this cannot be done. Choose one or the other (preferably `mysqli` over `mysql`)

Comment: Well, the rest of the snippet were purely html, except the connection to the database and table part, which are perfectly fine. I am suspecting the do while loop. Or not?

Comment: How are you telling AddToCart what product id to add to the cart?

Comment: All you are showing is a submit button. You allude to hidden inputs, but i dont see any. How you set the correct post data is likely the problem

Answer (score 0):

***This isn't an answer to fix OPs question, but a section to fix some of OPs "mistakes"***

### `header()`

When you're sending a header, make sure you `exit;` or `die;` straight after, as you want the code to stop and not process anymore.

```
header("location:prodtable.php");
die;
```

### `mysql` and `mysqli`

Choose one or the other. Preferably `mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated.

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

### Indentation

You have a mixture of indentation "techniques" and code design. Stick to one.

- Sometimes you have `{` on the same line as the condition, sometimes you have it on the new line.
- Sometimes you have indentation, sometimes you don't.

### Validate and sanitize input

You're relying too heavily on `mysql_real_escape_string()` which;

- Is part of a deprecated library
- Doesn't validate the input

Please validate the input before trying to insert it into the database. This will save a headache later should you expect something to be in the database and because of no data validation earlier, a particular system may fall over (and have a knock on effect).

```
  Is foo an int -------------- Kill process, tell user.
       |             (NO)
       | (YES)
       |
       |
   Ok. Do further checks
```

### Comments

Please use more of these, for your own sake.

***Yes, I know this isn't codereview.se, but they needed to be addressed. I've seen so many question that this post should apply to.***

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's the Product List.

```
    <!----- PHP CODES HERE ---------->
    <?PHP
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'abra', 'abra','abra') or die("Could not connect database");

$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products");
$prorow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

   ?>
```

```
<!-- TOP BAR -->
<div id="top-bar">

    <div class="page-full-width cf">

        <ul id="nav" class="fl">

        <?php   
            session_start();
            if(isset($_SESSION['SES_UNAME']))
                {
                    echo "<li class='v-sep'><a href='profile.php' class='round button dark menu-user image-left'>Logged in as <strong>".$_SESSION['SES_UNAME']."</strong></a></li>";
                }
            else
                {
                    header('location:   /loraine_mod/index.php');
                    exit();
                }
        ?>  


            <li class="v-sep"><a class="round button dark" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="v-sep"><a class="round button dark" href="prodtable.php">Product List</a></li>
            <li class="v-sep"><a class="round button dark" href="cart.php">My Cart</a></li>
            <li class="v-sep"><a href="logout.php" class="round button dark menu-logoff image-left">Log out</a></li>

        </ul> <!-- end nav -->

    </div> <!-- end full-width -->  

</div> <!-- end top-bar -->


<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div id="content">

            <div class="content-module">

                <div class="content-module-main" align='center'>
                <form method="POST" action="addtocart.php">
                    <table cols='5'>
                        <font face='algerian'>
                        <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2"><font face='times new roman' size='3'><center>Name</th>
                                <th colspan="1"><font face='times new roman' size='3'><center>Description</th>
                                <th colspan="1"><font face='times new roman' size='3'><center>Price</th>
                                <th colspan="1"><font face='times new roman' size='3'><center>Image</th>
                                <th colspan="1"><font face='times new roman' size='3'><center>Actions</th>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>

                                        <input name="proID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prorow['pId']?>">
                                        <input name="proName" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prorow['pname']?>">
                                        <input name="proPRICE" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prorow['price']?>">
                                        <input name="user" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SES_UNAME'] ?>">                      

                        <?php do { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['pname']; ?></td>
                                        <td colspan="1"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['pdesc']; ?></td>
                                        <td colspan="1"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['price']; ?></td>
                                        <td colspan="1"><center><img src="admin/<?php echo $prorow['image']; ?>" width="80" height="80" />

                                        <td colspan="1">
                                            <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to Cart">
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                 <?php } while ($prorow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>

                    </table>
                </form>
                </div> <!-- end content-module-main -->         
    </div> <!-- end content-module -->
```

Thanks for the suggestions, I'll take those.

Comment: Please remove this, and edit your question with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your input fields are outside your `do` loop, so the value will always stay the same - ie: will always be the first product.

```
<?php do { ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['pname']; ?></td>
    <td colspan="1"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['pdesc']; ?></td>
        <td colspan="1"><font face="times new roman" size="3"><center><?php echo $prorow['price']; ?></td>
            <td colspan="1"><center><img src="admin/<?php echo $prorow['image']; ?>" width="80" height="80" />

                <td colspan="1">
                    <input name="proID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prorow['pId'] ?>">
                    <input name="proName" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prorow['pname'] ?>">
                    <input name="proPRICE" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prorow['price'] ?>">
                    <input name="user" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SES_UNAME'] ?>">  
                    <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to Cart">
                </td>

                </tr>

            <?php } while ($prorow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>

            </table>
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed. The error (logical) was coming from a javascript used to update the shoppingcart page.

```
<script language="javascript">
function addtocart(pid){
    document.form1.productid.value=pid;
    document.form1.command.value='add';
    document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

Anyway. Thanks for your your answer guys. Will be posting a question in regards to this.